# Set Android Gallery widget to show specific starting image

Tags: android, android-widget, gallery

I have a task where the user can select an image from a GridView representing a photo album, and from this I start a new activity which displays a Gallery widget to show the images of the photo album. However, I can't seem to get the Gallery widget to show the contents of the photo album with a given image as the starting point. Ideally I would like a Gallery#setStartingImage(int position) or something similar.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After looking a little deeper into the inheritance hierarchy of Gallery, I found the method setSelection() defined in the AbsSpinner class which Gallery extends. This seems to do the job.

Comment: That's the perfect solution for this issue. You should mark the question as answered.

Comment: Okay, the question has been marked as answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After looking a little deeper into the inheritance hierarchy of Gallery, I found the method setSelection() defined in the AbsSpinner class which Gallery extends. This seems to do the job.